# Is it possible to show case comments from a lookup relationship?

Tags: visualforce, case

I have an object that has a lookup field to the case object. I am trying to create a VisualForce page that will show the case's case comments, but I can't seem to get it to work as intended.

I have tried two methods.

```
<apex:relatedList list="Case_Comments" subject="{!Case_Follow_up__c.Case__r.casecomments}"/>

<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Case_Follow_up__c.Case__r.casecomments}" var="c">
        <apex:column value="{!c.commentbody}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visualforce follows the same rules as SOQL. This means that you can only go "up" four relationships and "down" one relationship. You can't go "up one relationship, then down one relationship." It's certainly possible to display case comments natively *if* you were using Case as the standard controller. Instead, you'll have to query the comments in a controller method, and render those using an apex:pageBlockTable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can display Case Comments as a related list.  You need to build your own pageBlockTable and specify the columns.  Since you're on a custom object with a lookup to case, you may need a controller extension or a way to pass the caseID into the ID parameter for your page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
<apex:pageBlock >
You're looking at some related lists for {!case.casenumber}:
</apex:pageBlock>   

<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!case.casecomments}" var="c">
        <apex:column value="{!c.commentbody}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Source:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000095DsIAI